# VGA vs DVI vs DisplayPort with macbook AIR

Tags: display

I purchased DELL U2311H to use as external monitor on MBA 11.

I've three ways of hooking it up VGA DVI or DP.

I know VGA is analogue signal and DVI and DP digital. I have heard good things about DVI, but since my macbook has mini DisplayPort I thought going mini DP to DP would be the best quality wise.

What do you think? would it make difference?

I already have miniDP -> VGA converter, so all other options means I need to purchase converter.

Comment: You are not going to get any increase in qualify by using mini-displayport vs displayport the only real difference is the size of the connector and the fact Apple is the only one that really uses mini-displayport.

Comment: ha? sorry I don't understand. I'm not comparing miniDP to DP that would make no sense since my mac only has miniDP out port. I'm comparing miniDP -> DP vs miniDP -> DVI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used VGA (for decades) and DVI (for a couple of years) connections, and one thing that really sells DVI over VGA is that it includes clock-timing and sync information, getting the monitor to immediately perfectly assume the best settings, instead of VGA, where you have to try to get the monitor to "figure out" the best settings (regularly failing to grab optimal settings).

If DP adds anything to what DVI does SO VERY WELL, that doesn't sound like a bad idea.

> going mini DP to DP would be the best quality wise.

There is probably merit to this line of thought.  Personally, I would probably do that, unless a miniDP to DVI cable is significantly cheaper.